# unbind click doesn't work when using live

Tags: jquery, click

for some html element i need to remove other clicks functions using unbind or off function

but this too functions works just with click function 
as following :

```
 $("#test").click(function(){
  alert("test1");
  });
  $("#test").unbind('click').click(function(){ // or off
   alert("test2");
  });
```

but with live , this doesn't work and the two alerts are fired

```
 $("#test").live('click',function(){
  alert("test1");
  });
  $("#test").off('click').click(function(){ //unbind
   alert("test2");
  });
```

Comment: Don't use live(), use on().

Comment: @user1032531 You don't even know which version OP is using, so promoting on over live is kind of speculative.

Comment: @Christoph: He already using `off`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite of `.live()` is `.die()`: http://api.jquery.com/die/

```
$("#test").die('click').click(function(){ //unbind
  alert("test2");
});
```

BTW: `.live()` is deprecated since 1.7. But if you use an older version of jQuery I don't see a problem using it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(document).on('click','#test',function(){
  alert("test1");
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `.live()`, as it's deprecated.

Use `.on()` instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
```

Besides, `.off()` only unbinds event handlers bound with `.on()`. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for more information.

Comment: But that's not event delegation anymore.

Comment: It's not about making me happy, it's about helping the OP. Your code is equivalent to the first example in the question, so I don't see a point in showing the same with `.on`. The OP already knows how to unbind handlers when event delegation is not involved. Showing how to use `.on` as replacement for `.live` is more useful.

Comment: Of course I meant *"I cannot speak..."* and no worries, that happens quite often actually :D

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers.

And remember `off` is to use with `on` and `die` is to use with `live`